# Match string, but only if not preceded by other string

Tags: r, regex

Say I have vector of strings:

```
v = c("SPX.Close", "AAPL.Low", "Lo", "LowPrice", "PriceLow", "low")
```

How to write regex that would match all strings resembling phrase "low"?

`grep("lo", v, ignore.case=T) # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

This matches the first string too, which I don't want.

How to match `lo` **only if not preceded** by letter `c` ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Negative Lookbehind (PCRE in R)

R uses the PCRE engine, which supports lookbehind. Do this:

```
grep("(?<!c)lo", subject, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE);
```

The negative lookbehind `(?<!c)` asserts that what precedes the current position is not a `c`

**Option 2: Check for Capital Letter, Turn On Case-Insensitivity Inline**

Given your input, a more general option would be to assert that `lo` is not preceded by a capital letter:

```
grep("(?<![A-Z])(?i)lo", subject, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE);
```

For this option, we use the inline modifier `(?i)` to turn on case-insensitivity, but only after we have checked that no capital letters precede our position.

**Reference**

- [Inline Modifiers](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#modifiers)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)
- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my question to include "low" string in the data and still match it (i.e. `ignore.case=T`). Building on the rest of your answer, it seems that `grep("(?<!c)lo", v, ignore.case=T, perl = T)` works for me. Could you further interpret various symbols involved in the regex syntax please?

Comment: FYI, added a second option where we check that `lo` is not preceded by a capital letter (more general)

Comment: Is this possible without using a Negative Look Behind? The software I'm using does not support a negative look behind.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a negative lookbehind:

```
grep("(?<!C)lo", v, ignore.case=T, perl=T)
```

That will make sure that the string isn't preceded by C.

Comment: Thank you, I think `perl = T` argument is needed, otherwise it throws an error.